# How to indicate "doneness" in an async operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Given this code which counts the files in the given directory and subdirectories, how do I go about indicating that the operation is done?

```
function walkDirs(dirPath) {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = require('path'),
        events = require('events'),
        count = 0,
        emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

    function walkDir(dirPath) {
        function readDirCallback(err, entries) {
            for (var idx in entries) {
                var fullPath = path.join(dirPath, entries[idx]);
                (function statHandler(fullPath) {
                    fs.stat(fullPath, function statEach(err, stats) {
                        if (stats) {
                            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                                walkDir(fullPath);
                            } else if (stats.isFile()) {
                                count += 1;
                                emitter.emit('counted', count, fullPath);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })(fullPath);
            }
        }

        fs.readdir(dirPath, readDirCallback);
    }

    walkDir(dirPath);
    return emitter;
}

var walker = walkDirs('C:');
```

I've tried specifically,

- firing an event to indicate "doneness" at a place I thought appropriate, specifically after `fs.readdir(dirPath, readDirCallback)` call.
- modifying `statHandler()` to return the count added. (I realized that this is effectively no different from incrementing `count` inside that function.

Both of these failed, because when checked, the value of `count` is 0. I've determined that I'm not waiting until the operation (counting the files) is done. Obviously, I need to fire a callback or event when done to get the right count.

I know the code is successfully counting, because when attaching a debugger, the count value is as expected.

At this point, I've fairly certainly determined that I have no idea how to further proceed. Specically -

**How do I implement indicating "doneness" in an asynchronous operation?**

Comment: You should look into the concept of promises.

Comment: @Yatrix for example `q`, `node-promise` - ?

Comment: I don't know node at all. Just wanted to point you in the right direction. =)

Comment: @Yatrix there are many promises, you could use any of them, but I would advice `bluebird`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous Javascript functions generally call callback functions when they are finished. In this case, a `done` event would be appropriate if you have other events.  Promises are now often preferred over just callbacks, but you do need to understand callbacks first.

Since readdir is asynchronous, the execution being on the next line doesn't mean its finished.  That's what's confusing about asynchronous code compared to synchronous code.  If I were you, I would use the debugger and step through some really simple (simpler than this) async examples. It does take awhile to get used to and is tricky.

For walking directories see https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk .  You don't want to re-invent the wheel here.  Always be sure to Google and/or search on npmjs for existing modules.

Once you are sure you really understand callbacks and asynchronous code then you can move on to the `async` module, and after that, promises with `bluebird`, ES6 promises, etc.  Down the line something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/co may be useful.

Comment: I was more interested in how to compose async operations and know when to / how to indicate completion. It is very true that I was directory walking for any purpose other than learning how to async, I would definitely check npm / other sources before writing my own wheel. Regardless, thank you for the insight.

Comment: For an array full of async operations you can use things like `async.map` or `bluebird's` `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using promises. In this example I chose Q.

```
npm install q
```

You resolve your promise whenever you consider the async function to be done by calling the `.resolve()` function. When your promise gets resolved it will call your success-callback in then `.then()` function of you promise object, which is `walkDirs`. The `.then()` function get triggered whenever your promises get resolved or rejected. If you reject you promise the error-callback will be called.

```
var q = require('q');

function walkDirs(dirPath) {
    var deffered = q.defer();
    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = require('path'),
        events = require('events'),
        count = 0,
        emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

    function walkDir(dirPath) {
        function readDirCallback(err, entries) {
            for (var idx in entries) {
                var fullPath = path.join(dirPath, entries[idx]);
                (function statHandler(fullPath) {
                    fs.stat(fullPath, function statEach(err, stats) {
                        if (stats) {
                            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                                walkDir(fullPath);
                            } else if (stats.isFile()) {
                                count += 1;
                                emitter.emit('counted', count, fullPath);
                                deffered.resolve(emitter); // resolve promise
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })(fullPath);
            }
        }

        fs.readdir(dirPath, readDirCallback);
    }

    walkDir(dirPath);
    return q.promise;
}

walkDirs('C:')
   .then(success, error) //can also take error callback if promise is rejected.


function success(function(data) {
  //data = resolved data.
  console.log("is successfully done");
})

function errer(function() {
  console.log("is errorly done");
})
```

Comment: I think I've got the basic idea here. Your code doesn't function as-is but definitely points in what I believe to be the right direction. Thank you, I appreciate it.